# avoid writing df['column'] twice when doing df['column'] = df['column']

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I don't even know how to phrase this but is there a way in Python to reference the text before the equals without having to actually write it again?

** EDIT - I'm using python3 in Jupyter

I seem to spend half my life writing:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].some_changes
```

Is there a way to tell Python that I'm referencing the part before the equals sign?

For example, I would write the following, where `<%` is just to represent the reference to the text before the `=` (`df['column']`)

```
df['column'] = <%.replace(np.nan)
```

Comment: Are you using IPython or Jupyter notebooks?

Comment: Jupiter...always Jupiter lol

Comment: You _might_ be able to write a custom cell magic or whatever they're called... I'll see if I can write up an answer.

Comment: @user17242583 thanks, I appreciate your help! don't go to too much trouble though. I really thought this would exist already.

Comment: Nope, not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for **in place** methods.
I believe you can pass `inplace=True` as an argument to most methods in pandas

so it would be something just like

```
df['column'].replace(np.nan, inplace=True)
```

**edit**

You could also do

`df["computed_column"] = df["original_column"].many_operations`

so you still have access to the original data down the line.
And do all the needed operations at once instead of saving each step.

One of the advantages of inplace not being the default is if you are doing a batch of operations and it fails midway your data is not mangled.

Comment: yep, good point! you're right, it does work on a lot but not everything :)

Comment: I think that its not posible achieve that. Math operations can do it like df['a'] *= 5

Comment: i added an edit for why inplace not being default can actually be helpful